# How to setup the GNOME built-in OpenVPN configuration in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn

My system is Ubuntu 22.04, and OpenVPN has been included in GNOME. I don't know how to setup the OpenVPN configuration in Network Manager GUI. I need your help.

[image: OpenVPN setting GUI]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have ovpn file, import that file on the "Add VPN" window:

[image]